# Сакральный и сакраментальный.

Tags: лексика

Интересно, чем отличаются значения слов **сакральный** и **сакраментальный**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это, конечно, синонимы. Но кое-какие различия есть. Сакраментальный-больше значений: 
1) связанный с религиозным обрядом, ритуальный; сакральный;
2) священный, заветный;
3) о словах, речи: имеющий как бы магический смысл, звучащий как заклинание; ставший обычным; традиционный. Например, сакраментальная формула, произносимая в суде: "Клянусь говорить правду. Только правду. Ничего, кроме правды".Вот это значение "ставший традиционным, обычным" принимает значение и "формальный", некий отрицательный смысл.
[Фр. sacramentel -- сакраментальный; привычный < лат. sacramentum -- обязательство, клятва; таинство, от sacrare -- освящать, посвящать (богу), от sacer (ср. р. sacrum) -- посвящённый, священный.]
Сакральный -- священный, относящийся к религиозному культу и ритуалу; обрядовый. В анатомии "сакральный" означает "крестцовый, относящийся к крестцу". [Лат. os sacrum -- крестец, от os -- кость, sacrum -- священное(место, где находится деторожд. орган - священно)

Answer (score 1):

Никакие это не синонимы и близко! Сакральный: тайный, священный, даже магический. Это слово относится исключительно к религии или эзотерике — и больше ни к чему! А "сакраментальный" употребляется часто в переносном значении. Например "сакраментальная фраза", "сакраментальный момент в жизни".

Comment: Зачем так категорично? Это - паронимы. Но слово сакраментальный  в одном из значений - синоним слову "сакральный"
 Сакрамента́льный. Прил. 1. Священный, заветный. 2. Имеющий магический смысл, звучащий как заклинание (о словах, выражениях, речи). 3. то же, что сакральный  - Толковый словарь Ефремовой.

Comment: Не слишком резко: "Никакие это не синонимы и близко!"?Сейчас чаще используется переносное значение слова сакраментальный -" традиционный", но так было не всегда. В словаре Ушакова (издавался в 1935-1940 гг.) только одно значение – священный, заветный. В бумажном Ожегове 1961 г. изд. – то же самое дословно. А в Ожегове 1992 г.  уже два значения, в Малом академическом словаре 1984 г. – тоже.Первое значение никуда не исчезло, посмотрите словари, просто используется реже, потому что есть "сакральный"с этим же значением.Так что в первом значении синонимы.

Comment: Синонимы по "Словари и энциклопедии на Академике":сакраментальный,
заветный, обрядовый, обычный, освященный обычаем, освященный традицией, ритуальный, сакральный, ставший традицией, традиционный, укоренившийся